# Day of the week in the European numbering

Tags: javascript

This function work correctly.

```
function getLocalDay(date) {
   return (date.getDay() == 0) ? 7 : date.getDay();
}

alert( getLocalDay( new Date(2016, 0, 10) ) ); // 7
```

If I edit condition `date.getDay() ? 7 : date.getDay()` - function not working correctly. The function should return 7 if the day week Sunday.

Comment: `Date.getDay()||7` will give you what you need

Comment: @Akxe, nice. Why is my condition does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course! If you want to shorten your method you must write:

```
return !date.getDay() ? 7 : date.getDay();
```

You forgot the `!`.

You can also write `date.getDay() || 7` as @Akxe wrote in the comments.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about it. I am noob. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will work correctly. `date.getDay()` will return 0 for sundays, 0 is a falsey value, so the second branch of your condition will get called.

```
function getLocalDay(date) {
   return date.getDay() ? date.getDay() : 7;
}

alert( getLocalDay( new Date(2016, 0, 10) ) );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rwgqjegb/

Reference: [Truthy and Falsey](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Comment: Yes, but if I will edit condition `date.getDay() ? 7 : date.getDay()` - function will work wrong

Comment: Edited my answer and fiddle.